# Swift. Display image from website (xxx.?action=stream)

Tags: html, ios, swift, image

I want to display an image from a website. The problem is that the image is at "xxx.?action=stream"

I tried:

```swift
extension UIImageView {
public func imageFromUrl(urlString: String) {
    if let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
            (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
```

This works for images which have a file extension but not for the image in my case.

Website html code:

```html
<html>
    <body style="margin: 0px">
         <img style="-webkit-user-select: none; display: block; margin: auto; cursor: zoom-in;" src="http://1.1.1.181:8085/?action=stream" width="627" height="353">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to parse the HTML to find the image link. Use a library like Fuzi to do this.

Comment: @EricD Do you have any experience with Fuzi?
If so, can you give me an example?

Comment: I've made an example using Fuzi and your HTML snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, install [Fuzi](https://github.com/cezheng/Fuzi) - or any other capable third party, I'm just using this one for the example - and import it:

```
import Fuzi
```

Download the webpage itself as data with, for example, NSURLSession.

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(webpageURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    } else {
        if let data = data {
            // next code takes place here
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

Decode the data as a String then create an instance of `HTMLDocument`:

```
do {
    if let html = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: html)
        // next code takes place here
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.debugDescription)
}
```

The trick is then to inspect your HTML and understand the path to what you want to target.

From your example, you need to find the `img` tag and then fetch its `src` value.

Find the tag(s):

```
let path = doc.css("img")
```

Get its `src` attribute:

```
if let firstObject = path[0] {
    let link = firstObject["src"]
    print(link)
}
```

Complete example:

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(webpageURL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.debugDescription)
    } else {
        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let html = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: html)
                    let path = doc.css("img")
                    if let firstObject = path[0],
                        link = firstObject["src"] {
                        print(link)
                    }
                }
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.debugDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}).resume()
```

With your example HTML, this prints:

> http://1.1.1.181:8085/?action=stream

Now that you've got the image link, you can download the image itself.